# Prepend Integer Result with string text of "1:" to create ratio

Tags: sql, concatenation

The following query returns a single number, representing the `n` in a `1:N` ratio. Instead of just returning a single number, how can I prepend the integer value with the following text `1:` to give the result the correct ratio format?

```
select round((sum (case when unified_rollup_level_1 = "Company A" and person_type = "Employee" and worker_status = "Active" then 1 else 0 end)) /
    (sum (case when unified_rollup_level_1 = "Company A" and person_type = "Employee" and worker_status = "Active" and job_level IN ("08", "09") then 1 else 0 end)),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it would be for MySQL:

```
select 
    CONCAT("1:", round((sum (case when unified_rollup_level_1 = "Company A" 
                          and person_type = "Employee" 
                          and worker_status = "Active" 
                then 1 
                else 0 
                end)) /
                (sum (case when unified_rollup_level_1 = "Company A" 
                                and person_type = "Employee" 
                                and worker_status = "Active" 
                                and job_level IN ("08", "09") 
                            then 1 
                             else 0 
                      end)),0))
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! So, the problem I was running into was an issue with concatenating string text + integers. Script failed every time because of that. 

Had to first convert the integer to a string, lop off the decimals with a instr and left function (because for some reason the rounding function was ignored when converting to string) and then concatenate the quoted text with the newly converted string text "number".

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend text by just doing this:

```
SELECT "Foo" + stuff FROM table;
```

In this case, if stuff was 3, the result would be "Foo3" (without the quotes).

So in your case:

```
SELECT "1:" + ... -- the rest of it goes here
```